# Android: How can I use the Button background(style)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I want to use the button style on another control. 
How can I call that bg?

Comment: tagwise no change android:background . verify whether the 'control' supports background

Comment: yes it supports, what is the background for the button, so I can type it as background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give its background the attribute

```
@android:drawable/btn_default
```

Or set the style

```
@android:style/Widget.Button
```